# How to place div on an angle and match height to content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add this design to my webpage, but I am not able to match the height of right div to that of left div as shown in the second image
Can someone please help me?

Also in the mobile view, the squares are being displayed as one square per line, but I need 2 squares per line.

here is my code:

```
  <div class="container-fluid caffstudio">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 caffLeft">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- caff logo -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="cfimgdiv" style="display: inline-block">
              <img src="caffeine logomark.svg" class="imgcaff" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- caff text -->
          <div class="col-md-8" style="display: inline-block">
            <div class="cafftext">Caffine UX Design Studio</div>
            <div class="cafftext1">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Quisque velit cursus nulla aenean aliquam auctor orci.
            </div>
            <br />
            <a href="#" class="linkcaff mt-10">Visit Website</a>
          </div>

          <!-- first line of cards -->
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="img4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 im4div">
                  <div class="im4" style="display: inline-block">
                    <img src="experience.svg" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="im4txt" style="display: inline-block">
                    <div>5 yrs</div>
                    <div>Experience</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 im4div">
                  <div class="im4" style="display: inline-block">
                    <img src="projects.svg" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="im4txt" style="display: inline-block">
                    <div>25+</div>
                    <div>Projects completed</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 im4div">
                  <div class="im4" style="display: inline-block">
                    <img src="pipeline.svg" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="im4txt" style="display: inline-block">
                    <div>10+</div>
                    <div>Project in pipeline</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 im4div">
                  <div class="im4" style="display: inline-block">
                    <img src="screensdelivered.svg" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="im4txt" style="display: inline-block">
                    <div>1597</div>
                    <div>Screens delivered</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="z-index: 1;">
          <div class="multipleRect">
            <div class="twoRect">
              <div class="greyRect"></div>
              <div class="greyRect"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="twoRect">
              <div class="greyRect"></div>
              <div class="greyRect"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="twoRect">
              <div class="greyRect"></div>
              <div class="greyRect"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
.caffstudio{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #211E1E;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.greyRect{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #D9D9D9;
  border-radius: 18.6457px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.multipleRect{
  transform: rotate(12deg);
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

My code output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hUSm.png

Expected code output:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN793.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into flexbox and media query for when you are on mobile to get the boxes how you want them.

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .twoRect {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```